# Please explain the output. I am not able to understand the values of firstvalue and secondvalue

Tags: c++

```
// more pointers
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  int firstvalue = 5, secondvalue = 15;
  int * p1, * p2;

  p1 = &firstvalue;  // p1 = address of firstvalue
  p2 = &secondvalue; // p2 = address of secondvalue
  *p1 = 10;          // value pointed to by p1 = 10
  *p2 = *p1;         // value pointed to by p2 = value pointed to by p1
  p1 = p2;           // p1 = p2 (value of pointer is copied)
  *p1 = 20;          // value pointed to by p1 = 20

  cout << "firstvalue is " << firstvalue << '\n';
  cout << "secondvalue is " << secondvalue << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

**Output**

firstvalue is 10
secondvalue is 20

**but I think output should be**

firstvalue is 20
secondvalue is 10

Comment: why do you think the output should be different?

Comment: Why? After `p1 = p2;`, both `p1` and `p2` point to `secondValue`.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to abstract away the pointers, anyhow they are only there to create confusion and the program could be written without any pointers. See comments:

```
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
  int firstvalue = 5, secondvalue = 15;
  int * p1, * p2;

  p1 = &firstvalue;  // p1 points to firstvalue
  p2 = &secondvalue; // p2 points to seondvalue
  *p1 = 10;          //                             firstvalue = 10
  *p2 = *p1;         // secondvalue = firstvalue ie secondvalue = 10
  p1 = p2;           // p1 points to secondvalue
  *p1 = 20;          //                             secondvalue = 20

  cout << "firstvalue is " << firstvalue << '\n';
  cout << "secondvalue is " << secondvalue << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```